# I want add data from datagridview to another form - not display data

Tags: c#

I have form5 and form6 and use these code to display data from datagridview to textbox

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Form6 FRM = new Form6();
        FRM.ShowDialog();
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        Form5 frm = new Form5();

        frm.textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        frm.Show();
}
```

My question is: I want to add data to textbox not display data.

For example I have in textbox1 in form5 'mahmoud' I want to when action double click in datagridview to add 'johan' next to mahmoud

```
  mahmoud,johan,jjjj,kkkk,jjjj,ahaha
```

Answer (score 0):

try below codes

```
   string name =  dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   frm.txtCustomer.Text = name;
   frm.Show();

OR

  StringBuilder textvalues = new StringBuilder();
  textvalues.Append(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
  frm.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
string selectedText;
private void dGV1_doubleClick(....){
    selectedText= dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
    frm5.TextBox1.Text+= ","+selectedText;
    frm5.BringToFront(); //I suppose the form is opened.

}
```